# why is this pass by pointer is not working as intended?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-pointer

I am trying to understand why the following code does not work... please help:

```
void incme(double *p)
{
    printf("%x,%x\n",p,*p);
    *p = *p + 1;
    printf("%x,%x\n",p,*p);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    incme((double *)&i);    
    printf("%x,%x",&i,i);
}
```

the output is:

```
ff99a348,1
ff99a348,1
ff99a348,1
```

I am expecting:
    ff99a348,1
    ff99a348,2
    ff99a348,2
it breaks everything I know about pointers...

Thanks.

EDIT:

the main question i am asking the the type cast in incme((double *)&i); why isit not casting it to double and pass it to the function ? ... sorry for not pointing out eailer ....

Comment: size of int and double are not same

Comment: Step 1: get a [decent book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), step 2: read it.

Comment: the type cast in incme((double *)&i); will to cast the int to double ?

Comment: The type cast will cast the `int*` to a `double*`, which causes all the rules of C to fall out the window because you're not actually allowed to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Because of *undefined behavior*. Integers are not floating point, and floating point is not integers. Besides that, I think you will find that `sizeof(int) != sizeof(double)`.

You're also breaking the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

---

Unrelated to your question, you should use the `"%p"` format if you want to print pointers.

Comment: the type cast in incme((double *)&i); will to cast the int to double ?

Comment: @user1998844 No, it will cast a pointer to `int` to pointer to `double`. Integer values and floating point values are not encoded in the same way in computers, integers are stored as is in ther binary form while floating point values usually uses [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) encoding.

Comment: @user1998844 Besides that, because of the size difference and depending on machine [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) you could be writing to unallocated memory in your function.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `*p = *p + 1;` with p beeing a `double*` there is a lot going under the hood, indeed, double are represented using a custom format [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), when you use `printf` to display it as a integer after that, the internal representation of the memory at this address has changed (to a double representation), this is why you obtain such a result.

I ran the code and obtained the following output:

```
205afc2c,205afd28
205afc2c,593b4ab0
205afc2c,0
```

It shows use that the value is invalid as a double, and when it's incremented, it does not update the `sizeof(int)` first bits of the double (as it print 0 in the last line).

Hope I made myself clear !

#### Edit

I changed the code a little to show you what actually happen:

```
void incme(double *p)
{
    printf("%x,%lf\n",p,*p);
    *p = *p + 1;
    printf("%x,%lf\n",p,*p);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    incme((double *)&i);    
    printf("%x, %lf, %d",&i,i, i);
}
```

Gives me the following output:

```
cb90990c,0.000000
cb90990c,1.000000
cb90990c, 1.000000, 0
```

As you can see, if you print them as double, the value is indeed correct (but the binary representation of `1.0000` is not `00000000001` as I said previously, this is why the hex formatting gives you a large number).
Back in the main, if you display the value as a double (event if i is supposed to be a int) as the `incme` function changed the memory layout of it, it does print 1.0000, but the first 32bits of the memory at this address are 0 hence, printing it as an int gives you 0.

Comment: so the type cast at the function wont cast the i to double ?

Comment: It does cast it but as they do not have the same size or memory layout when you cast `int 1` to double, it gives you 0 because as a double it gives you a exponent of 0 (see the wikipedia page linked), and when you increment it, you get a 1 (in double representation, on 64bits) and thoses bits are lost when you print it back as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason, the printf statements should read -

```
printf( "%p,%f", p, *p );
```

This will show your increment of the double.

Also - as stated, an int is generally 4 bytes and a double uses 8 bytes. (on most systems)

Comment: For `%p` param should be `(void*)`